# Using reflection to test doInBackground() method in asyncTask

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-asynctask

The method signature of the doInBackground method in AsyncTask.class looks like this:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(MyObject... params);
```

And inside the test with reflection it looks like this:

```
try {
Method doInBackgroundMethod = asyncTaskInstance.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("doInBackground", MyObject[].class);
            doInBackgroundMethod.setAccessible(true);
            boolean success = (boolean) doInBackgroundMethod.invoke(asyncTaskInstance, myObjectInstance);
            Assert.assertTrue(success);
} catch ...
```

but I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch, on line "doInBackgroundMethod.invoke(asyncTaskInstance, myObjectInstance);"
```

Yes,I know there are two methods with the same signature, so I am searching for a solution for this problem.

Comment: It's "reflection", not "reflections".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `MyObject[].class` use `Object[].class` as doInBackground uses type set during init and automaticly casts to this type when invoking doInBackground but when you doing it manually - you also need to make cast manually.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. still get the same Error: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch"